# Should logging class be inserted as a dependency or should static method be used

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am aware that logging is a cross cutting concern and I normally use AOP for logging any errors or exceptions in general. However I am facing a scenario where we also have to log specific information about various operations performed, like for example when an operation was successful we have to log that also, we also have to log something if the response from a web service is invalid according to our business rules etc etc. This means that in some scenarios, logging an event becomes specifically part of the business flow and in these specific cases it is not a cross cutting concern.

To handle such scenarios I have made a DBLogger class that simply writes some dynamic messages and error codes to the DB.

Currently I am using the DBLogger class via dependency injection from ILogger interface. When I look at my code it seems like a code smell to me to see that I am injecting this class in every class where I need to log business rules violation. I am considering making the DBLogger class static and using it directly instead of injecting it. This will remove the code clutter a little bit and my constructor will be clean but the dependency will be still there.

**My question is what is the recommended way and best practice to handle such scenarios, and how can OOP and design patterns come to rescue in this case to stop me from violating the Open Closed Principal?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to inject the logger for the sake of unit testing. It makes it easier to mock the logger and avoid defining the dependencies of the real logger in your unit tests.

Besides if your IOC container defines it for you already, it's transparent and effort less to inject it.

Comment: Valid point TGH I guess the only smell or pain that I see currently is seeing that Logging class passed in as a dependency in every other class. That sort of makes me wonder if there is some other way! but you are right. It does add flexibility if I am injecting it.

Comment: I sometimes find it useful to define the logger in a base class to avoid the repeated code associated with having it defined in every class. However that approach doesn't always apply.

Answer (score 0):

'...in some scenarios, logging an event becomes specifically part of the business flow and in these specific cases it is not a cross cutting concern.'

Sounds like it should be unit tested then. Therefore it should be injected.

Consider decoration or, as TGH highlights, a base class to reduce the noise.

Comment: Excellent point David! If something is part of the business flow then it should be unit tested meaning that if the app is not performing that part of the code then it is not behaving properly. This testifies the need to inject that class.